# Find item in json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Lets say this object

```
var paises = {
        "isora":  {
             leftX: '275',
             topY: '60',
             name: 'Gran Melia Palacio de Isora'
        },
        "pepe":  {
             leftX: '275',
             topY: '60',
             name: 'Gran Melia  de Don Pepe'
        },
        "australia":  {
             leftX: '565',
             topY: '220',
             name: 'Gran Melia Uluru'
        },
        "otro":  {            //    ejemplo
             leftX: '565',    //    cordenada x 
             topY: '220',     //    cordenada y
             name: 'soy otro' //    nombre a mostrar
        }  /*                 <==>  <span class="otro mPointer">isora</span> */
    }
```

Allright as you can see it has a id (isora,pepe, australia,otro) and each of those has cordinades (leftX, topY) and another name to show (name)

I am using this to geo tag pictures,
i already done the part where i hover an item and i highlight in the map the cordinades and the name to show,   Now i need to do the opposite; if i hover the area in the map i need to highlight the item on the list (and in the map)

So lets say i have this mouse cordinades

```
x = 270

and     

y = 55
```

how can i check if there is any item (id)  with:
 x+-30 (leftX) AND y+-30 (topY) ??

+-30 is the margin of error (obviously is very dificult that users point exact cordinades with the mouse)

Comment: Without using (overly complicated) additional structures, you have to check every point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function find(x, y) {
    for (var key in paises) {
        if (paises.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var current = paises[key];

            if (Math.abs(current.leftX - x) < 30 && Math.abs(current.topY - y) < 30) {
                return current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then call it by;

```
var found = find(270, 55);

if (found == undefined) {
    // none found
} else {
    // found = the one found!
}
```

Of course, you can easily change the function to return a boolean if you don't need the one that was matched.

Comment: looks good! but this return something like: Object { leftX="275", topY="60", name="Gran Melia Palacio de Isora"} wich are the attributes but i won't know what id/name is? -EDIT- i only had to return key :)

Comment: If you need the name/id, just return `key` instead of `current`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var key in paises) {
    if (paises.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var item = paises[key];
        if (item.leftX > x - 30 && item.leftX < x + 30 &&
            item.topY > y - 30 && item.topY < y + 30) {
            // DO STUFF!
        }
    }
}
```

According to your description, you should rename `leftX` and `topY` as `centerX` and `centerY` instead.

But on another note, I would actually create clickable HTML elements instead using your object properties for positioning - and then hooking those elements up using the `click` event. That way, you'll never have to calculate anything, as you can change the size of the "clickable area" through simple CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could define a function that determines whether a point is inside the error margin:

```
function isInErrorMargin(px, py, vx, vy) { // p = reference point, v = actual point
    return vx >= px - 30
        && vx <= px + 30
        && vy >= py - 30
        && vy <= py + 30;
}
```

Then, iterate with `$.each`, checking each element:

```
var found;

$.each(paises, function() {
    if(isInErrorMargin(this.leftX, this.topY, x, y)) {
        found = this;
        return false; // stop
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function find(obj,test,args) {
    var ret = {};
    for(var i in obj) {

        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i) && test.apply(obj[i],args) === true) {
            ret[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

var paises = {
        "isora":  {
             leftX: '275',
             topY: '60',
             name: 'Gran Melia Palacio de Isora'
        },
        "pepe":  {
             leftX: '275',
             topY: '60',
             name: 'Gran Melia  de Don Pepe'
        },
        "australia":  {
             leftX: '565',
             topY: '220',
             name: 'Gran Melia Uluru'
        },
        "otro":  {            //    ejemplo
             leftX: '565',    //    cordenada x 
             topY: '220',     //    cordenada y
             name: 'soy otro' //    nombre a mostrar
        }  /*                 <==>  <span class="otro mPointer">isora</span> */
    }

var found = find(paises,function(x,y){
    if(this.hasOwnProperty("leftX") && this.hasOwnProperty("topY") && Math.abs(this.leftX - x) < 30 && Math.abs(this.topY - y) < 30) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
},[565,220]);
console.log(found)
```

This `find` algorythm searches in the `obj` (first argument) object for any object which return true to the test function (second argument). You can also pass arguments to the test function if you need.

Comment: Be sure to declare `i` (`for (var i in obj)`)

Comment: That answer doesn't take the 30 pixel margin or error into consideration. Also, you check the target property once for every existing property in the object you are checking. And you don't really check to see if the property is really defined in the object you are checking.